# How do I find out the first digit of a textbox value in asp.net/javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I would like to find the first digit of the value in a textbox in order to execute some conditional code. I can get the textbox by using getElementById, and would like to execute my code if the first digit contained within the textbox is 7, 8, or 9.

How can I test to see if the first digit of my textbox is between 7 and 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the script function on onkeypressevent like this

```
onkeypress="return urfunction(this);"
```

in function you will get the value like this

```
function urfunction(obj){var value = obj.value;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the script below to the "head" section of your html

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function validateTextBox()
{
  var input= document.getElementById("textboxid"); 
  if ( input != null)
  {
   //test the input.value here;
   //not sure what you need to do after the test...
  }   
}
</script>
```

Call the javascript function from an event,say on click event of a button on your page

```
<input type="button" value="Validate Text" onclick="javascript:validateTextBox()" />
```